# Replace first 4 rows with values from rows 5:8 arcpy

Tags: cursor, arcpy

I am trying to replace the values in the first 4 rows of a attribute table with the row values from the next 4 rows 5:8 in an attribute table using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor. Is there a simple way to index rows 1:4 (all columns) and replace with values from rows 5:8.

Here is my code thus far:

```
targetFC = r"D:\ZOC\POLYPGDIS_MASTER_1.shp"

dsc = arcpy.Describe(sourceFC)
fields = dsc.fields

# List all field names except the OID field

fieldnames = [field.name for field in fields if field.name != dsc.OIDFieldName]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(targetFC, fieldnames) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    row[1:4] = row[5:8]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to load the data into a list.
Note if you are working with a RDBMS the row order is not certain so this probably would not work unless you sorted by something.

```
eight_rows = []
k = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(targetFC, fieldnames) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        eight_rows.append(row)
        k += 1
        if k == 8: break
k = 5
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(targetFC, fieldnames) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        row = eight_rows[k]
        k += 1
        rows.updateRow(row)
        if k == 8: break
```